# Is there a way to debug JavaScript in the iPhone/iOS Safari browser?

Tags: javascript, iphone, browser

I have a strange behavior on the iPhone browser. Is there a tool to debug the JavaScript of the iPhone browser?

I'm hoping there's something more advanced than simple `alert()` messages.  Is there something with advanced tools like setting breakpoints and viewing object states?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

With the release of iOS 6, Apple released Remote Web Inspector for their Mobile Safari, and this is huge. Basically you have all the features and power of Web Inspector in regular Safari, for your mobile apps, including Phonegap apps.

I've used *weinre* but this tool makes it obsolete for newer versions of iOS (unfortunately not for old versions of iOS, non-iOS devices, or if you're on Windows) since its a full-featured debugger with breakpoints and everything.

#### Requirements:

1. A Mac with Safari 6+
2. Either a USB-attached iOS 6+ device or xCode 4.5+ running an iOS 6+ simulator

#### How to activate the inspector:

1. In your simulator or device, open **Settings > Safari > Advanced > Web Inspector > On**
   (this is on by default in the simulator)
2. In Safari 6+ for Mac, access your page from the Develop menu. You can enable Develop menu in Safari's Advanced Preferences if its not showing up.

   [image: Safari Web Inspector]

   [image]

More discussion at the bottom of:
http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/iphone-5-ios-6-html5-developers

(Also, if you read about a "secret private interface" or iWebInspector somewhere, these are also made obsolete.)

Comment: this blows any other solution out of the water - SUPER easy! Thx!!

Comment: I want to debug chrome on iOS, not Safari :/

Comment: @vsync in that case, its probably time to bust out the weinre. http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/Home.html

Comment: yes but it's not always simple to use it in some situations

Comment: @vsync I totally agree with you.

Comment: This helped a ton! Thanks

Comment: Can you use a mac in the cloud for iphone debug?

Answer (score 3):

check out [weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/) or use the remote version [debug phonegap](http://web.archive.org/web/20150301025719/http://debug.build.phonegap.com/).

cu

Comment: very nice - but is there a way to make breakpoints? I couldn't find it if there is...

Comment: i am sorry this is not possible. i had the same problem. so i used the console to debug my code... like

    `console.log("blablabla");`

Comment: @Robert, This _doesn't_ make weinre obsolete for iphone debugging. Not everyone has new or upgraded iPhone.

Comment: Fixed links. @AdrianBer

Answer (score 2):

you can also [inject firebug using a simple bookmark](http://martinkool.com/post/13629963755/firebug-on-ipad-and-iphone). I've used it on the ipad and my debugging abilities were immensely enhanced.

Comment: Thanks for your cool method. Is it possible to get through javascript step by step (on ipad/iphone)just like chrome browser hitting f12 and step through by hitting f10? Do you know any ios app or bookmarklet allowing that?

Comment: These days you should use the iphone simulator on macOS. Using Safari (has to be Safari I'm afraid, due to Apple reasons), you use the context menu to inspect any webpage (or webview inside your app). You get full dev tools including a debugger (step by step etc).

Answer (score 1):

I faced a simple use case in which I only needed to test my code on a Safari's JS engine (Merely debugging, simply running it and consuming traces).

To that end I used Epiphany web browser, which is both free and uses  JavaScriptCore JS engine which is also used by Safari.
Epiphany isn't provided with developer tools, so I used http://jsconsole.com/ to view my traces.

Though it is a thin solution, it helped me find a line which worked on Chrome but didn't on Safari.

Answer (score -4):

Step by Step Guide How To Enable JavaScript in iPhone

1. Open your iPhone settings.
2. Tap on safari in the app list.
3. Tap on Advanced option.
4. Enable Javascript iPhone with the help of switch push.