# How to debug JS browser app on iPad?

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, ipad

Some error occurs in my app on iPad. But I can not to debug it. 
I need just an error message.
How this can be solve on any browser, Chrome or Safari?
And I don't have Mac.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to debug JavaScript in the iPhone/iOS Safari browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242997/is-there-a-way-to-debug-javascript-in-the-iphone-ios-safari-browser)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debug ipad safari with a PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20408110/debug-ipad-safari-with-a-pc)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a laptop or desktop computer, Mac or not, you can debug web apps as if on a mobile device using some browser development tools.

Here is how you can toggle device mode in Chrome, for example:

[image]

Here is how to do it in Safari, assuming you've enabled developer tools:

[image]

Comment: Of course, I use it, but there's a huge difference between the emulator and a real device.

Comment: You might be out of luck if you are debugging an iPad. Apple explains it's mobile web debugging tools here: https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/ . This feature looks like it's only available on Safari for Mac's from what I can tell.

Comment: This question addresses a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26014850/debugging-mobile-safari-in-ios-8-and-ios-9 .