# Javascript error in website application causing it to not work on iphones

Tags: javascript, php, ios, iphone, ipad

A fellow developer created a web application for my website which is basically a form that clients fill in and then receive their results via email, the problem i am having is that it doesn't work on iphones or ipads, it seems to get stuck at the mailing stage and emails aren't sent out,the application works perfect on all other devices including macs, this isnt just a Safari issue either as it doesn't work using Chrome on the Iphone/Ipad either.

I think its a problem with the javascript but I don't have enough javascript knowledge to find the issue.

The developer who created it has now left and i have no idea how to fix the problem, the link to the page on my site is:

http://thepowerwithinlifecoach.com/wheel-of-life.php

I have been struggling with this for weeks now so if anyone has any ideas to fix it that would be great

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242997/is-there-a-way-to-debug-javascript-in-the-iphone-ios-safari-browser

Comment: i don't have a mac so i cant use the debugger

Comment: As far as I know, you can do it with any OS, as long as you have the same browser, and a USB cable.

Comment: I have tried with using safari on windows as well as using a virtual PC with ios installed and didn't work so as far as i have tried it has to be done on a mac

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to put in your php header 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin and set this one . If after that it will not work then you need to remove any animations libraries which you are using here then try again becz some time with iphone animations libraries conflicts I had the same problem before 6 months..

You need put following code in your database connection file on the top

```
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: access");
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS");
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
  header("Expires: -1");
```

Comment: can you please help with the Access-Control-Allow-Origin i am not familiar with how to use this, can you please show me the code i need to put in the php? thanks