# Development for Android and iPhone/WinPhone

Tags: android, ios, html, windows-phone-7, cross-platform

It's been suggested to me from two different sources that it's possible to develop for all the three major mobile device platforms using HTML5. Apparently, according to them, one can write code and deploy to all three at the same time.

Now, my impression was that iPhone is a C++ thing and WinPhone C#, while Android is powered by Java. How mistaken am I?

Comment: TL;DR: iPhone is Objective C (Apple's butchered up version of C with OOP paradigms), WinPhone is XNA/Silverlight using .NET architecture (C#).

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161004/using-phonegap-for-native-application-development

Comment: You can develop using C++ for Android using its NDK. You only have to use Java for the entry point.  But you need a very good excuse to do so.

Answer (score 3):

There were framework to do such a thing. Have a look at things like [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/), [MoSync](http://www.mosync.com/), [Sensha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch) or [Apache Cordova](http://incubator.apache.org/cordova/).

Comment: PhoneGap and Cordova are the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.  However, you can develop a webpage using HTML5 that can look and kindof act like an app that works for all platforms at once.  But this is not an app in any sense, just a cheap way of getting the job done.

Comment: Aha! I **knew** that! That's what I was suspecting but I had to ask. You never know... Thanks! But you're saying that no matter what, I'll be limited to a browser window, right? And the user **will know** he's working in a browser presenting him a web page...

Comment: Well, you could create an app that doesn't do anything but display that webpage.  So if you do a really good job you might not be able to tell its only a webpage.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use html5 to develop web page applications, but if you wan't to use it for apps on different operating systems:try corona.

---

I prefer iOS development with Xcode, but I have heard that corona is great for cross platform programming and easy to use.

Comment: @Chamster Because you didn't ask the question.

Comment: @Chamster: You either logged in using different credentials or you chose not to link your accounts when they were created. Linked accounts will appear on your profile page (see [mine as an example](http://stackoverflow.com/users/390989/eldarerathis)) and yours do not appear to be associated with each other. You can [start here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18232/150283) for information that may help you connect them (it's difficult to specifically state the instructions since it's unclear what your exact situation is).

Comment: @eldarerathis You're right. I **thought** I had the same account info since I log in using my Google account but apparently something went poo... Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the answer is yes.  You can use the MoSync SDK (for example) to create an app in C++, and it will build to Android ARM code, or use Xcode and Visual Studio (under the hood) to create native apps.

You can create native apps in HTML and JavaScript.  The HTML is used as a declarative API for creating native widgets.  You get actual native widgets, not just HTML which looks like the native widgets.