# checklist of creating phonegap project- Can SomeOne add More elements

Tags: javascript, android, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

FOR UPDATED LIST PLS SEE THIS URL

http://www.aurigait.com/blog/checklist-of-creating-phonegap-project/

1. We will be doing core HTML dev. But Jquery Mobile Can be used as a platform for its wide range device support & ease in making forms with a tradeoff of performance on lower-end devices.
2. UI transitions are not supported in various devices either we can selectively apply transitions.
3. iOS and android navigation to be kept same or different since back button navigation in available in android
4. Language / Audio / Tectical Support
5. Analytics / Notifications and Intensity [Notificatioin Pages History]  / Adwords / geolocation based
6. Resposive layout resolution breakup
7. We will be supporting resolutions of 320*480 and Above. (for that we can have a UI Designs for 320*480 (mobile Portrait) / 768*1024  (tablet Portrait) / 1280*720 (Desktop)
8. Updates & News
9. Event Calender & Reminders
10. User feedback Forms
11. swipe gestures
12. Sharing of all the content from the application
13. Single page applications [Single Page layouts effectively implement those. (follow examples of paytm / asana / gmail)]
14. Bringing html directly from server with UI just being a container of view.
15. Using application transforms like Mobstac for this. / xslts / transforms
16. Single page applications [Single Page layouts effectively implement those. (follow examples of paytm / asana / gmail)]
17. Bringing html directly from server with UI just being a container of view.
18. Using application transforms like Mobstac for this. / xslts / transforms.
19. Sharing for ios and android
20. back button navigation support
21. Documentation of the application/admin panel is needed
22. Export options of reports

(1)Back button navigation support in android is very important should be planned from the day 1 of development cycle. In IOS back button must be provided for desired navigation. 
Remember android and iOS have different navigation patterns.

```
 document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false); //onBackKeyDown
```

(2)avoid using Form elements inside pages because there is just no use, you will never submit.

(3)for phonegap splash screen please use navigator splash hide() rather than autohide=true and timeout.

```
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="false" />
```

(4)android splash landscape is supported so pls put landscape splash images as well into the system (for iOS we are looking into it)

(5)when using cloud build for phonegap and then native build remember to delete the repo’s images since if using cloud build images will be uploaded as a zip package increasing the size of application.

(6)for android and ios different JS for plugin maintain seperate files remember only one repository will be kept for android and iOS in SVN there will be no exception.

```
   <!--iOS / Android cordova
    <script src="js/ios/cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>-->
     <script src="js/android/cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
     <!--android cordova-->
     <script src="js/android/flurry.js"></script>
     <script src="js/android/PushNotification.js"></script>
     <script src="js/android/AdMobPlugin.js"></script>
     <script src="js/android/share.js"></script>
     <script src="js/android/ExecutePlugin.js"></script>
    <!--iOS / Android cordova  
    <script src="js/ios/AdMobPlugin_iOS.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ios/flurryPlugin_iOS.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ios/PushNotification_iOS.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ios/iOS_Execute.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ios/share.js"></script>-->
```

(7)Do not use Javascript confirm box and alerts use Native boxes. They look good

```
navigator.notification.confirm("Do You want to Exit Km?", function (idx) { if (idx == 2) { navigator.app.exitApp(); } }, 'Exit Application', 'No,Yes');

function Native_Alert(msg) {
    if (navigator.notification != undefined) {
        navigator.notification.alert(msg);
    }
    else
        alert(msg);
}
```

(8)When using list select use native option list and check list because they look better. Not the html select items

```
 <select id="Select2" name="Select2" data-role="none" >
                    <option>Town</option>
                </select>
```

(9)inorder to remove white overlays for android 4.0.3 element use below

```
input{
   -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;}
```

(10)Never do preferred installation SD card not supported in ~android 2.2

(11)screen width can not change for a mobile app only vertical scroll can come with some exceptions. Screen sometimes moves outside areas should be taken care Only at the time of writing markup and css.

(12)native loading panels for Android and iOS are preferred Due to Their BLOCKING nature.
http://abstractlayers.com/2013/03/09/phonegap-adding-progress-dialogspinner/

(13)dynamic and eval script registering and De-registering

(14)Phonegap childbrowser can not be trusted for loading every content we can use, open windows in New Browser outside phonegap instead you can use InAppbrowser.

```
function OpenLinkinNewWindow(weblink, sharecontrol, subjectval) {
    try {

        if (global_deviceType == undefined || global_deviceType == "")
            global_deviceType = (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) == "iPod" ? "iOS" : (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) == "iPad" ? "iOS" : (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) == "iPhone" ? "iOS" : (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) == "Android" ? "Android" : (navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)) == "BlackBerry" ? "BlackBerry" : "other";
        switch (sharecontrol) {
            case 'facebook':
                weblink = 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=' + encodeURI(weblink) + '&t=' + encodeURI(subjectval);
                break;
            case 'twitter':
                weblink = 'http://twitter.com/share?text=' + encodeURI(subjectval) +'&url=' + encodeURI(weblink);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        consoleLOG('sharer weblink : ' + weblink);
        //incase of videos android and iOS have different problems while loading videos since childbrowser can open vid for on IOS
        if (global_deviceType == "Android")
            navigator.app.loadUrl(weblink, { openExternal: true });
        else if (global_deviceType == "iOS")
            window.open(weblink, '_system', 'location=yes'); //andriod changes
        else
            window.open(weblink); //andriod changes
    }
    catch (ex) { consoleLOG('error in OpenLinkinNewWindow : ' + ex); window.open(weblink); }

}
```

(15)application offline check with html5 features

(16)while creating iOS Native build please copy the references into the folder of the build otherwise build will have issues while porting to another system.

(17)phonegap cloud build must be Locked to particular version of phonegap otherwise it will create build for latest RC versions which may have bugs. config.xml file should be read thoroughly before using the feature of phonegap build.

(18)for creating next android and iOS build the version must be updated to version 1.0 + 0.1 or what is suitable.

(19)keep the application namespace, bundle id correct  at the first moment because you Can never change that once app is deployed on app / play store. [*dont put com.demo.demoApp]

(20)Keep the apple provisioning and distribution profiles in backup as well as developer profile for any mac you are using since the application code base & certificates, public keys and p12 file is very dependent on Macs.

(21)disable unwanted permission for android and iOS to avoid unwanted components to be loaded and also its shown on app stores permissions tab and while installation user may get confused by seeing unwanted permissions being required by the application.

```
<plugins>
    <plugin name="App" value="org.apache.cordova.App"/>
    <plugin name="Geolocation" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker"/>
    <plugin name="Device" value="org.apache.cordova.Device"/>
    <!-- commented <plugin name="Accelerometer" value="org.apache.cordova.AccelListener"/>
    <plugin name="Compass" value="org.apache.cordova.CompassListener"/>
    <plugin name="Media" value="org.apache.cordova.AudioHandler"/>
    <plugin name="Camera" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher"/>
    <plugin name="Contacts" value="org.apache.cordova.ContactManager"/>-->
    <plugin name="File" value="org.apache.cordova.FileUtils"/>
    <plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager"/>
    <plugin name="Notification" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification"/>
    <plugin name="Storage" value="org.apache.cordova.Storage"/>
    <plugin name="FileTransfer" value="org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer"/>
    <plugin name="Capture" value="org.apache.cordova.Capture"/>
    <!-- commented <plugin name="Battery" value="org.apache.cordova.BatteryListener"/>-->
    <plugin name="SplashScreen" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen"/>
    <!--<plugin name="Echo" value="org.apache.cordova.Echo" />-->
    <plugin name="Globalization" value="org.apache.cordova.Globalization"/>
    <plugin name="Share" value="com.schaul.plugins.share.Share"/>
  </plugins>
```

(22)No hover css classes will be applied for the mobile application for any cases. hover is not used in mobile and otherwise it creates Issue.

(23)[Using Phonegap for Native Application development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161004/using-phonegap-for-native-application-development)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for updated list please check this URL
http://www.aurigait.com/blog/checklist-of-creating-phonegap-project/

(24)Known issue of Tap Highlight

```
input
{
   -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
}

*:hover, *
{
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
}
```

(25)Debug specification for various devices you can deploy wienry remote debugger on node.js settings. Console.log logging, log shipping, Error Handling must be put at each javascript function.
(26)CORS cross domain request must be converted to JSONP requests: CORS is not supported by mobile browsers and sometimes we need cors for running the application for testing on mobile browsers. There is a workaround avaiable. GET.PHP script can be put at the localhost to pick JSON data. This will be reroute cross domain request to localhost request and CORS error will not come.

```
var Global_URL = http://xxxxxx:8080/WWW/local_native/assets/www/get.php?url='http://www.remoteserver.com/JSONDATA?q=12';
<?php
$url = $_GET['url'];
$page = file_get_contents($url);
echo $page;
?>
```

(27)backup android keystore and protect it like your firstborn child 
      backup all ios certificates and protect them.

(28)disable web security Batch file for chrome

```
cd C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\
chrome.exe --disable-web-security
```

(29)Application will not run on tablets

```
 <!--<supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
            />-->
```

(30)disable all unneeded permissions

(31)Android 2.2 and above and IOS 5.1 above
(32)production namespace for android and iOS 
(33)Application name iOS dot dot showing issue
(34)`<preference name="disallowOverscroll" value="true" />`
(35)if correct json is not coming from server

```
function GetJSONifNeeded(data) {
    if (typeof data == "object")
        return data;
    else
        return JSON.parse(data);
}

function GetJSONstringfyifNeeded(data) {
    if (typeof data == "object")
        return JSON.stringify(data);
    else
        return data;
}
```

(36)How to Apply Touch event instead of click

```
href = "<a class='applymenutouch' data-ele='" + i + "' >";
$('.applymenutouch').on('touchstart', function () { alert(render_submenu_link($(this).attr('data-ele'))); })

//SECOND BETTER WAY dynamic click to touch event convert
[a] touchsliderTopNewsMob = '<li><a data-click="javascript:Review_ShowArticle(' + page_id + '  class="classt">'
[b]ApplyTouch('classt');
[c]function ApplyTouch(cssclass) {
    $.each($('.'+cssclass), function (idx, elm) {
        var tapping = false;
        $(elm).on('touchstart', function () { tapping = true; });
        $(elm).on('touchmove', function () { tapping = false; });
        $(elm).on('touchend', function () {
            tapping && eval($(this).attr('data-click'));
        });
        $(elm).removeClass(cssclass);
    });}
```

Comment: dynamic click to touch event convert
**[a]** `touchsliderTopNewsMob = '<li><a data-click="javascript:Review_ShowArticle(' + page_id + '  class="classt">'`
[b]`ApplyTouch('classt');`
[c]`function ApplyTouch(cssclass) {
    $.each($('.'+cssclass), function (idx, elm) {
        var tapping = false;
        $(elm).on('touchstart', function () { tapping = true; });
        $(elm).on('touchmove', function () { tapping = false; });
        $(elm).on('touchend', function () {
            tapping && eval($(this).attr('data-click'));
        });
        $(elm).removeClass(cssclass);
    });}`

Answer (score 1):

14.. Forget about this solution if you want to publish your app to Apple store. It will be promptly rejected.

**Revisited**: Bringing raw data from server and using jQM application to generate front end GUI

16.. Performance improvements depending on a platform, mostly on Android 2.X. Phonegap and jQM are know to badly underperforme on older Android platforms.

17.. Add much more complex set of touch gestures with hammer.js (compatible with jQuery Mobile)

18.. If possible make app more native looking by using Phonegap plugin for native nav/tab bar on iOS and Android platform (will help to make app more acceptable during the publishing process).